# JavaFX WebView: Disabling Websocket

Tags: java, javafx, websocket, javafx-11

Is there a way to programmatically disable Websockets temporarily on JavaFX `WebView`? I can disable Javascript via the `WebEngine`, but I can't seem to find the method to call for disabling and enabling Websocket. I'm using JavaFX 11.